# Upgrading to PHP 5.6.7 using remi repos

Tags: centos, php, yum

I have PHP 5.6 enabled in my remi.repo file and <s>none of the other sections are enabled</s> the only other section enabled is `[remi]` itself.

```
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php55]
...
enabled=0
...

[remi-php56]
name=Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/php56/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/php56/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

When I run `yum install php`, I get an error saying that my httpd-mmn version is wrong, but the version it requires is an old one.

```
Error: Package: php-5.6.7-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Installed: httpd-2.4.6-19.el7.centos.x86_64 (@updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-17.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (base)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-18.el7.centos.x86_64 (updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
```

I find this very odd, because this process worked on the last server I updated.

Is this a bug in my version of remi.repo?

Comment: which version of httpd is using your server? is different from the last server you updated?

Comment: On the previous server, it was `/Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)/Oct 16 2014` and now it's `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)/Jan 12 2015`. But we used `remi` before as well. So the only thing I can think of is that `remi` changed something in their dependency list that caused php to ask for the wrong version of httpd.

Comment: Just discovered that I'm using CentOS 7 where it should have been CentOS 6. That doesn't change the fact that the remi PHP has some issues with CentOS 7, but I can probably avoid them by switching back to 6.

Comment: I would avoid starting a _new_ project on EL6, if possible. You're running the latest PHP, but much older versions of everything else - including the web server itself! This will limit you in the future in ways which are hard to predict in advance, beyond the obvious one of being unable to use features that don't exist in those old versions. Presumably you want the latest PHP for current functionality; why not for the rest of the stack?

Comment: @Michael That's a good point and I will bring it up with my team members. At the time that my other team members decided to use CentOS 6, el7 was not available from our hosting provider, so we will have to ensure that we weren't depending on any el6-specific features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it told you specifically:

```
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
```

You have also installed the [remi repositories](http://rpms.remirepo.net/) for EL6, but you are actually running EL7. You also need to correct this by using the EL7 repos instead. The easiest way to do this is to install the appropriate [remi-release RPM for EL7](http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, I just reinstalled remi and the file now correctly has `[remi]` and `[remi-php56]` enabled and I'm still getting the message. (I've updated my question with the actual error message.)

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius Oops, looks like you have one more thing to fix.

Comment: Just to reiterate what I said above, I didn't realize until now that I had installed CentOS 7 instead of CentOS 6. Our hosting provider recently switched from 5 & 6 to 6 & 7, hence my mistake when choosing from the list. You are right that that is the problem - I apologize for not understanding this fact sooner.